Use C++ to control GPIO on Raspberry Pi5
Excuse
I want to control GPIO according to C++.
But I found that the GPIO libraries existing now aren't available to use on Raspberry Pi5.
And some libraries aren't available in Ubuntu.
How could I deal this problem?
